# C# out of memory Exception in System.Drawing.dll

Tags: c#, exception, timer, listbox, out-of-memory

i made a slideshow using c#, the code running well and doesnt give me any error, but when i hit play button after 30-60 seconds it stops and gives me out of memory Exception System.Drawing.dll . any idea to solve this problem? Thank You

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace Slide_Show
{
    public partial class SlideShow : Form
{
    public SlideShow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        if (timer.Interval < 200)
        {
            timer.Interval = 100;
        }
        else if(timer.Interval > 8000)
        {
            timer.Interval = 600;
        }
        else{
            timer.Interval = 2000;
        }
    }
    string dir;
    private void btnImagesSelection_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        FolderBrowserDialog asked = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        if (asked.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string folName = asked.SelectedPath;
            foreach (string fullfol in Directory.GetFiles(folName))
            {
                dir = fullfol.Substring(0, fullfol.LastIndexOf(("\\")));
                picImages.Image = Image.FromFile(fullfol);
                lstImages.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(fullfol));
                lblNum.Text = lstImages.Items.Count.ToString() + "/" + lstImages.Items.Count.ToString();
            }
        }

    }

    private void lstImages_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string curitem = lstImages.SelectedItem.ToString();
        picImages.Image = Image.FromFile(dir+"\\"+curitem);
        lblNum.Text = (lstImages.SelectedIndex+1).ToString() + "/" + lstImages.Items.Count.ToString();
    }
    bool flip = true;
    int i = 0;
    private void btnPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        timer.Start();
        timer.Interval = 1000;
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timetick);
    }
    void timetick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int numitems = lstImages.Items.Count;
        if (flip)
            if (i < numitems)
            {
                try
                {
                    lblNum.Text = (i + 1) + "/" + numitems;
                    picImages.Image = Image.FromFile(dir + "\\" + lstImages.Items[i].ToString());
                    i += 1;
                }
                catch
                {
                    timer.Stop();
                }
            }
            else if (i == numitems)
            {
                i = 0;
            }
        flip = !flip;
    }

    private void btnSlow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            timer.Interval *= 2;
        }
        catch
        {
            timer.Interval = 6000;
        }
    }

    private void btnFast_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            timer.Interval /= 2;
        }
        catch
        {
            timer.Interval = 100;
        }

    }

    private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer.Stop();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: you arent disposing of any of the images you load

Comment: Before assigning a new one insert `if(picImages.Image != null) picImages.Image.Dispose();`

Comment: @TaW you should not dispose an Image before assigning new. It can cause an error

Comment: No, it won't. Unless you enforce it with a `picImages.Refresh();`. But this doesn't happen here, so it is safe.

Comment: @TaW it can also happens when you resize the window. Obviously this error is hard to get, but we should avoid it.

Comment: Indeed we should. But as there is no code going to run between the two lines here 'hard to get' still seems a little to dramatic ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Image` class holds image data as unmanaged resources. These resources can't be unloaded by `Garbage Collector` and the memory will be freed when you call `Dispose` method or by [finalization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.finalize(v=vs.110).aspx). Finalization is too slow to handle lots of Images so every time you load new Image you should dispose the old one.

```
private void LoadNewImage(string path)
{
    var oldImage = picImages.Image;
    picImages.Image = Image.FromFile(dir+"\\"+curitem);
    if(oldImage!= null)
    {
        oldImage.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also try to use GC.Collect() and GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers() after calling the oldImage.Dispose(). Although they are quite an expensive operations, I sometimes used to get OutOfMemoryExceptions even if I called the Image.Dispose() method.